# Laravel Response::json() exhausts memory

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4.2

I have an application which sometimes returns chunks of HTML; in this case I have to return a large table and the memory gets exhausted.

I have a macro set up, which checks that the data to return is not larger than the allowed json limit;

```
Response::macro('jsonWithValidation', function($response) {
    if(strlen(serialize($response)) > 125000000)
        $response = array(
            'status' => 200,
            'execute_also' => array(
                'notify("warning", "Data too large to be sent over json");'
            )
        );

    return Response::json($response, $response['status']);
});
```

This script works as a charm; the problem I'm facing now is that **the last `Response::json` exhausts memory**. This means that my response is not too large to be sent over json, but the Laravel method (I'm running Laravel 4.2) crashes everything.

Ideally, at this point of the code I could have two options:

- send everything with basic php, but I believe the Laravel function is pretty basic already
- clear the memory I won't need for the response

Ideally I would like to use the second option, but I have no idea if this could be done... so **what should I do to avoid exceeding memory limit?**

EDIT:
This is the error I get

```
[05-May-2016 14:19:42 Europe/Rome] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\project_ski\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 446
```

Comment: You make a check but generate JSON anyway! Just don't do it if the check fails.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. If you feel memory is only problem in your case then set a content length based on your response size.

```
    $response = Response::make($contents, $response['status']);
    $response->header('Content-Length', strlen(serialize($response));
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'json');

return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the nature of this json size limit, why do you feel that it needs to be implemented?

serialize() does not generate json data, so you are not even checking the same thing you claim. Moreover, you are running the same heavy operation twice.

A better approach would be something like this:

```
Response::macro('jsonWithValidation', function($response) {

    $return = Response::json($response, $response['status']);

    if(strlen($return) > 125000000)
        $return = array(
            'status' => 200,
            'execute_also' => array(
                'notify("warning", "Data too large to be sent over json");'
            )
        );

    return $return;
});
```

Also, if you are returning an error, http status code should not be 200 OK. More here: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html